# SQL Server Express is not installed on your system

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

When I try to open code for an existing ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2015, it shows a warning like

> [image: SQL Server Express is not installed on your system]

In that application, there is a connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />'
```

I have SQL Server 2012 installed in my system.

Comment: This is not how to connect to 2012.  cf https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy:

1. Attach that `.mdf` file that's being referenced in the original connection string to your SQL Server 2012 instance
2. Change the connection string to the new situation - something like:

   ```
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```
3. Just simply ignore that VS warnings if it ever occurs again ....

The reason for the warning is the `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true` setting of the original connection string; this approach (which I **DO NOT** recommend at all) **only** works with the Express edition of SQL Server - not with any other editions.